# How to use IPv6 for kubernetes service ip space?

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, centos7

I work in a company where almost all private ipv4 space is already used, so using 10.254.0.0/16 for service address space is a non-starter.  I have carved out a /64 of ipv6 space that I can use, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here's my apiserver config:

```
# The address on the local server to listen to.
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--address=::"

# The port on the local server to listen on.
KUBE_API_PORT="--port=8080"

# Port kubelets listen on
KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"

# Address range to use for services
# KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=fc00:dead:beef:cafe::/64"

# Add your own!
KUBE_API_ARGS=""
```

But when I try to start `kube-apiserver.service` I get an error about "invalid argument".  Is it possible to use IPv6 for kubernetes?

Comment: By the way, the IPv6 range you are using, `fc00:dead:beef:cafe::/64`, is in the reserved range that you are not supposed to use. While the `fc00::/7` range is for ULA, the first half of the range, `fc00::/8` is actually reserved to be assigned by a yet-to-be-named global authority. The second half of the range, `fd00::/8`, is available for local assignment, but the next 40 bits MUST be chosen by a pseudo-random number generator. See [RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses, Section 3.2 Global ID](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193#section-3.2).

Answer (score 3):

[I don't think IPv6 is fully supported](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1443). I don't think there is a strong motivation among the developers of the project to add IPv6 support, because the largest group of contributors is [Google employees](http://stackalytics.com/?project_type=kubernetes-group&metric=commits). Google Compute Engine (and thus Google Container Engine) doesn't support IPv6, so it wouldn't benefit Google directly to pay their employees to support IPv6. Best thing to do would probably be to pull in employees of companies that run their hosted product on AWS (as AWS has IPv6 support) such as RedHat, or try to contribute some of the work yourself.

From the linked PR, it looks like Brian Grant (Google) is, for whatever reason, somewhat interested and able to contribute IPv6 support. He'd probably be a good resource to query if you're interested in contributing this functionality to Kubernetes your self.

Answer (score 1):

AWS already made IPv6 by default for almost all of their major services -- 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ipv6-support-for-ec2-instances-in-virtual-private-clouds/

Recently, [the IPv6 support is accepted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1443), one by another started too, in-fact, the POD implementation has done so far. k8 is moving towards Service and then issues.

Currently, the open blocker issues are still open with good use cases --
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27398